Error: Could not find or load main class Djava.library.path=C:\Windows\System32\jnetpcap.dll Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
Error: Could not find or load main class Djava.library.path=C:\Windows\System32\jnetpcap.dll
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Djava.library.path=C:\Windows\System32\jnetpcap.dll
I did :
<1> build path
enter image description here
<2> run configurations -> vm arguments enter image description here
<3> CLASSPATH : %JAVA_HOME%\lib;.

Edit the question with all details, not images. It looks like you have wrong library path (it should contain dirs) and set system property without using -D.
